# Bootstrap datatable is not resizing and fitting with the container when i view the page in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap Datatable in a web application. When i view the same web page within the mobile, the datatable goes outside the bootstrap container. Even in the desktop, if i reduce the size of the browser window beyond certain point i see the same behaviour

```
  <div class="container">
            <form id="myform" class="form-horizontal"
                action=/testUrl method="post" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <table id="myhist" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">id</th>
                                    <th scope="col">name</th>
                                    <th scope="col">age</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>Test Name</td>
                                    <td>40</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>Test Name2</td>
                                    <td>42</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your

```
<div class="col-sm-11">
```

to

```
<div class="table-responsive">
```